# MySQL Get distinct counts from different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have several tables, given below:

Company:

| company_code | ceo |
| --- | --- |
| "C1" | "John" |
| "C2" | "Andrew" |

Lead:

| lead_code | company_code |
| --- | --- |
| "LM1" | "C1" |
| "LM2" | "C2" |

Senior:

| lead_code | company_code | Senior_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "LM1" | "C1" | "SM1" |
| "LM1" | "C1" | "SM2" |
| "LM2" | "C2" | "SM3" |

Manager:

| lead_code | company_code | Senior_code | Manager_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "LM1" | "C1" | "SM1" | "M1" |
| "LM2" | "C2" | "SM3" | "M2" |
| "LM2" | "C2" | "SM3" | "M3" |

Employee:

| lead_code | company_code | Senior_code | Manager_code | Employee_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "LM1" | "C1" | "SM1" | "M1" | "E1" |
| "LM1" | "C1" | "SM1" | "M1" | "E2" |
| "LM2" | "C2" | "SM3" | "M2" | "E3" |
| "LM2" | "C2" | "SM3" | "M3" | "E4" |

I want to print out CEO, total number of leads, seniors, managers and employees grouped by the company code. My output should look like this:

O/P:

C1 John 1 2 1 2

C2 Andrew 1 1 2 2

How should I approach this?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate first, and then join with the main table. For example:

```
select
  c.*, l.c, s.c, m.c, e.c
from company c
left join (select company_code, count(*) as c from lead group by company_code) l on l.company_code = c.company_code
left join (select company_code, count(*) as c from senior group by company_code) s on s.company_code = c.company_code
left join (select company_code, count(*) as c from manager group by company_code) m on m.company_code = c.company_code
left join (select company_code, count(*) as c from employee group by company_code) e on e.company_code = c.company_code
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT company_code, ceo, COUNT(DISTINCT lead_code) as total_lead, COUNT(DISTINCT Senior_code) as total_senior, COUNT(DISTINCT Manager_code) as total_manager, COUNT(DISTINCT Employee_Code) as total_employee
FROM
(
SELECT Company.company_code, ceo, Lead.lead_code,  Senior.Senior_code, Manager.Manager_code, Employee.Employee_Code
FROM Company
LEFT JOIN Lead
ON Lead.company_code = Company.company_code
LEFT JOIN Senior
ON Senior.company_code = Company.company_code
LEFT JOIN Manager
ON Manager.company_code = Company.company_code
LEFT JOIN Employee
ON Employee.company_code = Company.company_code
)
GROUP BY company_code, ceo;
```